# Microphone in Windows Phone 8 extending audio capture using c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, audio-recording

I wanted to develop a audio recording app for Windows Phone in c# and I found a link on the internet.

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Audio_recording_and_playback_options_in_Windows_Phone

To my surprise, I found that I could not record for more than 20 minutes. That might be due the byte size restriction or any other memory allocation issues. Could someone help me on that.

Answer (score 2):

Actually that is because the Memory cap for Windows Phone apps. Read  the limitations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx).

As a solutions you can detect the memory cap for the device and then divide a longer recording in to smaller parts. But user doesn't need to do this manually, you can programmatically do this. In your case you you tested this on a 512MB device/emulator so 20 mins is the limit.

So divide the recording in to 15 min sections. You can use `Coding4Fun` Toolkit's `MemoryCounter` to monitor how much memory you use so you can decide where to break the recordings for each of the Memory capacities